# Erro no VBA EXCEL "Não é possível definir a propriedade Hidden da classe Range"

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou executando o código a seguir em no evento Open de uma pasta de trabalho do Excel. Está dando erro em tempo de execução '1004', "não é possível definir a propriedade Hidden da classe Range". Veja o código:

```
Sub ConfigIni()
   
Dim senha As String
    
' Desativa atualização de tela para melhorar o desempenho
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Obter a senha da célula (6, 13) da planilha Edicao
senha = Edicao.Cells(6, 13).Value

' Proteger e desproteger a planilha
Simulador.Unprotect Password:=senha
Simulador.opt_Gestor = False
Simulador.opt_ConsultorVendas = True
Simulador.Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Edicao.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Simulador.lbl_Margem.Visible = False
Simulador.txt_DataCompra.Visible = False
Simulador.Protect Password:=senha

' Chamar as macros definidas em módulo2
Application.Run "módulo2.ClassificarPlanilha"
Application.Run "módulo2.CarregaDados2"

' Reativa a atualização de tela
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
End Sub
```

O erro é na linha 15 "Simulador.Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True". O que pode ser  ser? Já tentei reescrever o código de outras forma e não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [especificação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns) da classe `Columns`, você deve referir pelo índice ou pela letra (`"I"`). O intervalo (`"I:I"`) seria usado para a classe `Range`.

Portanto, você deve usar um dos dois:

```
Simulador.Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Ou:

```
Simulador.Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```